# Changing base url of Freeform paginate links

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, pagination, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to change the base url on Freeform paginate links as it is with channel entries?

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/pagination.html#paginate-base

I have a page that loads some Freeform entries via ajax and I need the links to point to the main page rather than the ajax one.

I can't seem to see it mentioned in the Freeform docs. At the moment I'm using jQuery to dynamically change the links, but it'd be nice to be able to specify it in the tag variables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Freeform 4.1.8, it doesn't support changing the paginate base, but we will add it in as a feature request.